# how to use top level async await with typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've a typescript project, when i use `await xxx.someAsyncMethod(..)` at the top level, typescript linter shows,

```
Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'esnext' or 'system', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.
```

so I'll change the module to esnext `"module": "esnext"`

and i'll go ahead and try running the program `npx ts-node app/app.ts`

then console informs me

```
(node:15509) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

upon setting the type to module in package.json `"type": "module"` when i run the program the console out puts

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/apple/Desktop/source_given_to_me/Git/bots/wab/app/app.ts
    at Loader.defaultGetFormat [as _getFormat] (internal/modules/esm/get_format.js:65:15)
    at Loader.getFormat (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:113:42)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:244:31)
    at Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:17)
```

what can be done so i can get away with using top level async await?

**EDIT:**
my redis.ts file

```
import * as pm from "child_process"
var prc:pm.ChildProcess;

async function startRedis(path:string): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log('starting redis')
        var rp = pm.spawn(path)
        rp.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
            console.log(data)
            console.log('redis fired up')
            prc= rp
            resolve(true)
        })
        rp.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
            console.log(data)
            console.log('redis failed to start')
            resolve(false)
        })
    })
}

function active():boolean{
    return prc?!prc.killed:false
}

async function stopRedis(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve)=>{
            if(prc){
                resolve(prc.kill("SIGTERM"))
            } else {
                resolve(false)
            }
        }
    )
}


export const redis = {
    startRedis,
    stopRedis,
    active
}
```

my config.ts file (tsconfig.json is below)

```
export const config = {
    redisPath:'../r607/src/redis-server'
}
```

my app.ts file

```
import {config} from "./config.js"
import {redis} from "./redis.js"
//import * as pm from "child_process"

await redis.startRedis(config.redisPath)
if(!redis.active()){
    process.abort()
}
```

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "esnext",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "ESNext",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
     "outDir": "./build",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007 . Especially this part: *" Idiomatic TypeScript should import `foo.ts` as `import 'foo.js';` TypeScript understands this."*

Comment: Could you paste your code and tsconfig.json file?

Comment: simple workaround for this kind of stuff is to use in you main file async IIFE and do all async stuff inside that.

like:
```
(async boot() {
await foo();
})()
```

Comment: @MarekUrbanowicz yeah thats what I am using right now, thank you

Comment: @FelixKling i did that without any luck

Answer (score 15):

Follow these steps:

- Add `"type": "module"` to your package.json.
- Replace `"main": "index.js"` with `"exports": "./index.js"` in your package.json.
- Update the `"engines"` field in package.json to Node.js 12: `"node": "^12.20.0 || ^14.13.1 || >=16.0.0"`.
- Add [`"module": "ES2020"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) to your tsconfig.json.
- Use only full relative file paths for imports: `import x from '.';` → `import x from './index.js';`.
- Remove `namespace` usage and use `export` instead.
- Optional but recommended, use the [`node:` protocol](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_node_imports) for imports.
- **You must use a `.js` extension in relative imports even though you're importing `.ts` files.**

if you use ts-node
use it like:

```
node --loader ts-node/esm ./entrypoint.ts
```

Edit:
source [gist](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c)

Comment: This looks awfully similar to https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c

Would you have forgotten to credit the initial author?

Comment: In addition to being copied, this answer omits any context. Better information can be found here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#top-level-await

Comment: Thank you. Adding only this, worked for me: ```Add "type": "module" to your package.json.```

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve the same results with this pattern:

```
async function main(): Promise<void> {
    const foo = await somePromise
    console.log(foo)
}

main()
```

Even though you aren't `await`ing main, NodeJS won't exit until the event queue is empty. In other words, it won't exit while there are unresolved promises.

Comment: The question is 'how to use top level async await with typescript?'. This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @mikemaccana But it is still a nice workaround. Upvote it

Comment: @aristotll No it's not. What if you need to await `main()` and do more things after it?

Comment: @Devin In that case, `main` isn't main :) You should probably name it something different, then do `async function main() { await myRenamedFunction(); doMoreStuff(); }`